# Storing IndexLARQ to Disk

Tags: java, lucene, jena

I'm reading a .nt file into a Apache Jena model and indexing it. I would like to store this on disk but am having trouble doing so.

This is what I have:

```
IndexBuilderString larqBuilder = new IndexBuilderString();
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.register(larqBuilder);
FileManager.get().readModel(model, "sample\\titles.nt");
System.out.println("Finished Reading!");
larqBuilder.closeWriter();
model.unregister(larqBuilder);
IndexLARQ index = larqBuilder.getIndex();
```

I've tried using index.getLuceneReader() which returns an IndexReader and explored trying to write the contents to file, which ended up leading to a dead end.

Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this what TDB is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ./tdbloader which solved the problem of loading large datasets